# Moving web part zone from the bottom to the right in wiki pages

Tags: 2007, web-part, wiki, web-part-zone

I have a Wiki pages that I need to add a Web Part to. When I go to Site Actions, Edit Page and scroll to the bottom of the Wiki page I can click Add a Web Part and go through the process to get this set up as I want.

My problem is that I need this Web Part to display at the right side of the page, not the bottom and the only zone available seems to be Bottom.And I want to Keep This setting for Every Wiki Page Which will be create in the future. IS anyone has a solution for this case?

Comment: You'll need to modify the library template. I'm unfortunately not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Text layout option for wiki-pages.
Open wiki-page -> Site Action: Edit page -> Select Format Text tab (Editing tools) on Ribbon -> Select Text layout option -> f.e. One column with sidebar layout.

Comment: Under The Site Action, I only have Create, Edit Page and Site Setting. I didn't see Format Text tab. I forget to mention that I'm using MOSS 2007. Not 2010. Anyway Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

On the page editing bar, select page settings from the page menu item. From there, you can select the page layout used in the same way you did when the page was created. All your data (text, webparts etc) should still remain in place. (publishing feature must be activated)

Comment: I found neither Page Editing Bar nor page setting inside wiki page even in site setting. How you get there?

Comment: sorry, try this:
from: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101513941033.aspx

Insert a Web Part zone

In Office SharePoint Designer 2007, open the page where you want to insert the Web Part zone.
If the Web Parts task pane is not already open, open it by clicking Web Parts on the Task Panes menu.
In Design view, click the location on the page where you want to insert the Web Part zone.
At the bottom of the Web Parts task pane, click New Web Part Zone.